# does linux shell support list data structure?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ash

this question is not the same as [Does the shell support sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314319/does-the-shell-support-sets)

i know lots of script language support list structure, such as python, python, ruby, and javascript, so what about linux shell?

does shell support such syntax?

```
for i in list:
do
     print i
done
```

i would first to **initialize a list**,  for example:

```
ListName = [ item1, item2, ..., itemn ]
```

**then iterate over it**

is that possible when programming shell scripts?

Comment: Note also that Bourne shell / POSIX shell doesn't have arrays. But the `for item in list of items; do` construct is certainly supported in all shells. Note also the convenient use of globbing to loop over a set of files; `for file in a*.dat` constructs a list of tokens by expanding the wildcard (though sadly, many users manage to wreck it by doing something like `for file in $(ls a*.dat)`).

Answer (score 145, accepted):

It supports lists, but not as a separate data structure (ignoring arrays for the moment).

The `for` loop iterates over a list (in the generic sense) of white-space separated values, regardless of how that list is created, whether literally:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

or via parameter expansion:

```
listVar="1 2 3"
for i in $listVar; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

or command substitution:

```
for i in $(echo 1; echo 2; echo 3); do
    echo "$i"
done
```

An array is just a special parameter which can contain a more structured list of value, where each element can itself contain whitespace. Compare the difference:

```
array=("item 1" "item 2" "item 3")
for i in "${array[@]}"; do   # The quotes are necessary here
    echo "$i"
done

list='"item 1" "item 2" "item 3"'
for i in $list; do
    echo $i
done
for i in "$list"; do
    echo $i
done
for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo $i
done
```

Comment: What does the @ mean??

Comment: It's a special index that causes the expansion to produce all elements of the array, not just one specific element.

Comment: I didn't get why `for i in "${array[@]}";` prints 3 lines. Since `echo ${array[@]}` prints a single line `item 1 item 2 item 3` , I would expect that `for i in "${array[@]}";` is converted in `for i in "item 1 item 2 item 3";` ; so it would result in a single line `item 1 item 2 item 3`. What am I missing? Thanks in advance

Comment: `"${array[*]}"` would expand to `"item  1 item 2 item 3"`. `"${array[@]}"` expands to `"item 1" "item 2" "item 3"`; it treats each element as a separate quoted word, rather than a single quoted word containing every element.

Comment: array only works in bash shell. Is there a way to achieve same in KSH?

Comment: What makes you think `ksh` doesn't support arrays? It does, but the syntax is a little different in places. This answer and its comments isn't the place to explain the differences.

Answer (score 19):

For make a list, simply do that

```
colors=(red orange white "light gray")
```

Technically is an array, but - of course - it has all list features.
Even python list are implemented with array

Comment: To iterate over the array, use `for item in ${colors[*]}; do echo $item; done`

Comment: @Neevek that won't do what you think it does; "light gray" will be treated as two items "light" and "gray". You need to use `"${colors[@]}"` (`@` not `*`, and quoted).

Comment: why "light gray" will be treated as two items when * is used? where i can find documents for such details? man sh?

Comment: Basically that's a historical flaw, `$*` in the Bourne shell didn't work correctly in all situations and so `"$@"` had to be invented.